# Is there a simpler way to check if a variable equals a variety of numbers?

Tags: php

This is what i have currently

```
if ($j == 1 || $j == 2 || $j == 3)
```

Is there a simpler way of writing this. Something like...

*pseudocode*

```
if ($j == 1-3)
```

Comment: A word to the wise: `1-3` is -2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way using [in_array()](http://php.net/in_array)

```
if (in_array($j, array(1,2,3)))
{
    //do something
}
```

Or how about using [range()](http://php.net/range) to make the array

```
if (in_array($j, range(1,3)))
{
    //do something
}
```

However, building an array just to check a narrow, contiguous range like that is pretty inefficient. So how about simply:

```
if ($j >= 1 && $j <= 3)
{
    //do something
}
```

If other values of $j will trigger different action, a switch might be more appropriate...

```
switch($j)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        //do something
        break;        

}
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's a range, you can simply do:

```
if ($j >= 1 && $j <= 5) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Paul's good one, but if you have a large number then you may want to use `range`:

```
if (in_array($j, range(0, 100)))
{

}
```

Comment: You can achieve exactly the same with if ($j >= 0 && $j <= 100) without creating an array with 100 elements, and wasting memory.