# Combining many || in an if statement

Tags: php

Is there a cleaner way to do something like this, without having to repeat `$var` that many times?

```
if($var == "A" || $var == "L" || $var == "N" || 
   $var == "Q" || $var == "U" || $var == "V")
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a simpler way to check if a variable equals a variety of numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636229/is-there-a-simpler-way-to-check-if-a-variable-equals-a-variety-of-numbers)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do `in_array`. Put the right hand side in a array.

So...

```
$arr = array("A", "L", "N", "Q", "U", "V");
if (in_array($var, $arr)) {

}
```

This is simple for maintainability. If you have anything more complex, a `switch` might be best.

Comment: If you are doing this check multiple times also consider flipping the array and doing a fast hash lookup.

Answer (score 4):

Try using an array and `in_array()`

```
$check = array('A','L','N','Q','U','V');

if (in_array($var, $check)) { //Stuff }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

For example:

```
$items = array("A", "L", "N", "Q", "U", "V");
if(in_array($var, $items)) {
    //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
$a = array("A", "L", "N", "Q","U", "V");
if (in_array($var, $a)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put the letters into an array, then use `in_array`.

```
$letters = array('A', 'L', 'N', 'Q', 'U', 'V');
if(in_array($var, $letters)){
  // Do Something
}
```

Or you can use a `switch`.

```
switch($var){
  case 'A':
  case 'L':
  case 'N':
  case 'Q':
  case 'U':
  case 'V':
    // Do Something
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `if (strpos("ALNQUV", $var) !== false)`?

Comment: What if $var is AL, NQ, QU etc .. ?

Comment: @Diode: What if it isn't? :-) It depends on the OP's setup, really... if you want, you can add a check for `strlen($var) == 1`...

Comment: if (strpos("ALNQUV", $var) !== false && strlen($var) == 1)

Comment: @Diode:  Consider using `isset()` instead of `strlen()` when checking for arbitrary string lengths (ex. `!isset($var{1})` instead of `strlen($var) == 1`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for this

Answer (score 0):

create an array with A,L,... and check whether $var is equal to it and if it is not keep $temp as 1 and check whether $temp is 1 outside

Comment: use for loop for checking or use in_array