# If condition is not working properly

Tags: php, if-statement

I implemented if condition in my code, Condition is if john is set than show abc.jpg else xyz.jpg but it is not working it shows me the the xyz .jpg image everytime. Please help me. If my syntax is wrong than please tell me where is the mistake.

```
<?php
if($extra = "John" || "Kevin" || "Cameron" || "Santosh" || "Ali"){ ?>
    <img src="http://yespricer.com/theme/Freshness/images/maria2.png" width="75"/>
<?php }else{ ?>
    <img src="http://yespricer.com/theme/Freshness/images/maria.png" width="75"/>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank god no ones said about using ' because they are faster than ". Oh, wait, D'OH! ><

Comment: The syntax is fine, but you have expressed something different and code than you wanted to. http://php.net/expressions

Comment: Hi, if any of below answers has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) or adding your own solution. So, that it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if `$extra` is equal to value every time. Your code does this only once. You can group all the values inside an array and check wheter your value is in it:

```
$names = array("John", "Kevin", "Cameron", "Santosh", "Ali");
if(in_array($extra, $names)) {
    // $extra is in $names
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
if($extra == "John" || $extra == "Kevin" || 
   $extra == "Cameron" || $extra == "Santosh" || 
   $extra == "Ali"){

}
```

**EDIT**

As **des** suggest `in_array` you can use this solution also

```
$names = array("John", "Kevin", "Cameron", "Santosh", "Ali");

echo "<img src='http://yespricer.com/theme/Freshness/images/"
  .(in_array($extra, $names)?'maria1':'maria')
  .".png' width='75'/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Very similar way to what others above have suggested but a little tidier in my opinion

```
<?php
    $name = "";
    if($extra == "John" || $extra =="Kevin" || $extra =="Cameron" || $extra =="Santosh" || $extra == "Ali"){ 
        $name = "maria2.png";
    }else{
        $name = "maria.png";
    }
?>
<img src="http://yespricer.com/theme/Freshness/images/<?php echo $name;?>" width="75" />
```

Answer (score 0):

#### A better and efficient way is to use `in_array()`:

```
<?php
if(in_array($extra, array("John", "Kevin", "Cameron", "Santosh", "Ali")){ ?>
    <img src="http://yespricer.com/theme/Freshness/images/maria2.png" width="75"/>
<?php }else{ ?>
    <img src="http://yespricer.com/theme/Freshness/images/maria.png" width="75"/>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You Can't Use**

```
if($extra = "John" || "Kevin" || "Cameron" || "Santosh" || "Ali"){
```

**Reason Why**

Because if you go from left to right, $extra == "John"... ok, thats fine because it could evaluate to true or false depending on the value of $extra. However, the next one is like doing this:

```
if ("Kevin") {
```

Since non empty strings evaluate to true, you had might as well have written this:

```
if($extra = "John" || true || true || true || true){
```

Since you are using logical OR, it does not matter what $extra is, because every single one will result in the if condition being TRUE.

**Solution 1 - Messy Conditional**

```
if($extra == "John" || $extra == "Kevin" || $extra == "Cameron" 
|| $extra == "Santosh" || $extra == "Ali"){
```

**Solution 2 - As des Suggested**

```
$names = array("John", "Kevin", "Cameron", "Santosh", "Ali");
if(in_array($extra, $names)) {
    // $extra is in $names
}
```

**Solution 3 - Cleaner than ifs, Faster than arrays & still flexible**

```
switch ($extra) {
    case "John":
    case "Kevin":
    case "Cameron":
    case "Santosh":
    case "Ali":
        //code here for TRUE, if any of those names match $extra


        break;
    default:
        //code here for FALSE, if non of the names match $extra



}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to learn more about what is happening? Assign your condition to a variable:

```
$result = $extra = "John" || "Kevin" || "Cameron" || "Santosh" || "Ali";
```

Then make your condition visible:

```
var_dump($result);
```

This will give you:

```
bool(true)
```

Meaning that the condition resulted in boolean `true` ([demo](http://codepad.org/GRafeqbn)). Why does this happen you might ask yourself now. For that you can pick the condition apart:

```
"John" || "Kevin" || "Cameron" || "Santosh" || "Ali"
```

This is an expression of `true` in PHP. You can replace it just with `true`. The next part then:

```
$extra = true;
```

That is easy. You assign `true` to the variable `$extra`. Now the final part:

```
$result = true;
```

Again, now assigning the result of the expression to `$result` so you see `true`.

Instead you probably wanted to check that the variable `$extra` contains any of the names. There are some caveats here in PHP to do that properly. First of all make your life easier and put all names you would like to check against into an array:

```
$names = array("John", "Kevin", "Cameron", "Santosh", "Ali");
```

Then check *strictly* that `$extra` is in that array:

```
$result = in_array($extra, $names, true);
```

Note the third parameter being `true` here, that is for strict checking (see [`in_array`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/in_array)). Otherwise you might see that if `$extra` is `0` that `$result` is true. Then process the result, but make your life easy again, you just need a variable:

```
$image = $result ? 'maria2.png' : 'maria.png';
```

And then finally do the output:

```
printf(
    '<img src="http://yespricer.com/theme/Freshness/images/%s" width="75"/>'
    , $image
);
```

And you have solved your issue. The code example in full:

```
$names  = array("John", "Kevin", "Cameron", "Santosh", "Ali");
$result = in_array($extra, $names, true);
$image  = $result ? 'maria2.png' : 'maria.png';
printf(
    '<img src="http://yespricer.com/theme/Freshness/images/%s" width="75"/>'
    , $image
);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/iywZshyj)

See as well:

- [Is there a simpler way to check if a variable equals a variety of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1636229/367456)
- [Combining many || in an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8566641/367456)